# CGAL 3D surface mesh generation for unbounded implicit surfaces

Tags: mesh, cgal, triangulation

This is again a question about the CGAL 3D surface mesher.

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html#Chapter_3D_Surface_Mesh_Generation

With the definition

```
  Surface_3 surface(sphere_function,             // pointer to function
                    Sphere_3(CGAL::ORIGIN, 64.0)); // bounding sphere
```

(as given too in the example code) I define an implicit surface given by 'sphere function' and a Sphere_3 of radius 8.

The difference is now, that the zeros of 'sphere function' are (contrary to its now misleading name) no longer bounded and inside Sphere_3. Instead 'sphere_function' represents an unbounded surface (think of x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1 = 0) and my intention is to triangularize its part that is in the Sphere_3.

In my examples up to now this worked quite well, if only for some annoying problem, I do not know how to overcome: The boundaries, where the implicit surface meets the Sphere, are very "rough" or "jagged" in a more than acceptable amount.

I already tried the 'Manifold_with_boundary_tag()', but it gave no improvements.

One road to improve the output that I am contemplating, is converting the triangulated mesh (a C2t3) into a Polyhedron_3 and this in a Nef_polyhedron and intersect that with a Nef_polyhedron well approximating a slightly smaller Sphere. But this seems a bit like shooting with cannons for sparrows, nevertheless I have currently no better idea and googling gave me also no hint. So my question: What to do about this problem? Can it be done with CGAL (and moderate programming effort) or is it necessary or better to use another system?

(Just for explanation for what I need this: I try to develop a program that constructs 3D-printable models of algebraic surfaces and having a smooth and also in the boundaries smooth triangulation is my last step that is missing before I can hand the surface over to OpenSCAD to generate a solid body of constant thickness).

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I see is to use the 3D Mesh Generation with sharp feature preservation and no criteria on the cells. You will have to provide the intersection of the bounding sphere with the surface yourself.
There is one example with two intersecting spheres in the [user manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#title25).

Comment: You could mesh in a larger sphere. And you find the faces that intersect the small sphere. This then gives you sharp features to protect.